# sql define function

Tags: sql, string, range

How to use the "define" variable function in sql server 
when I would like to define ID starts with "JH"?

For example,  DEFINE DATE = '11-JUL-16' does not work in this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Date DateTime;
SET @Date = '11-Jul-2016'
```

As for defining an actual user function as your title suggests, your DEFINE statement isn't even close to the proper syntax.

From what I can actually put together, you want a function something like this:

```
CREATE Function MyDate
(
    @id varchar(50),
) RETURNS INT --or whatever you want to return
BEGIN
   IF @id LIKE('JH%')
      RETURN (SELECT var1, var2) from Table1
      WHERE Table1.var1 = @id
   ELSE RETURN (SELECT var1,var2) from Table2
END
```

Then call the function

```
SELECT dbo.MyDate('JH1022') as Result
```

I have no clue where Date comes into play but this should get you the gist of how a SQL function works

Comment: Thanks Adam! How if I would like to use id starts with 'A', and I don't want to call ID like 'A%' all the time, just want to define ID_code at the very beginning.

Comment: Well, using the like statement is the method of doing it. You could use a `bit` to evaluate an if else by checking with a like statement and then just use the result of the bit in place of the `like('A%')`